# A bootstrap menu doesn't work correctly in Symfony2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, menu

I am developing a web site using Sympfony2. In fact, I created a twig file called "tes2.html.twig". Its code is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/bootstrap.min.css')}}"/>
    <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/bootstrap.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/src/jquery.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body> 
        <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <input type="image"  id="notifications" alt="notifications" src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/notifications.jpg')}}"/>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><span>hello</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I see the output of that file, I see the button below on the screen:

[image]

The issue is when I click on that button no item appears despite I checked the paths out in the code above. By the way, you can have a look at the screenshot below to get sure about that:

[image]

As you can notice above, I respected the path of each source file (I mean: bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js, jquery.min.js and notifications.jpg). So my question is what is the error in my code ?

Comment: Get your code working with hard coded URLS in the HTML first. Then once it works on the client side replace those URLs with ones generated by Symfony2

Comment: Use your browsers dev tools to figure out which URLs aren't working

Comment: @Jon Winstanley: yes I tried that using HTML and it worked!!..I can't understand why that code doesn't work in Symfony2!!!

Answer (score 0):

- open firebug and select console
- hit or refresh the page then look for error loading java script and css

i believe these are missing in your env, that is because when i copy and paste  your code here - it works!

> http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h

Or try the reverse by replacing your code with the working code here

> http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

, if this does not work you know it is your required javascript or css for bootstrap to work does not load.

- be sure your page load with no error by looking at the console tab of firebug.